# Unity 2D game Scale player on Key press don't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a little game in [unity](/questions/tagged/unity) for the first time, but I now face a little problem with scaling the "player" on a keydown event.

Here is my [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) script code:

```
void Update(){
    //if we are on the ground and the space bar was pressed, change our ground state and add an upward force
    if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        anim.SetBool("Ground",false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
    }
    if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
    {
        //HERE I NEED THE SCALE.
        //player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x 1, transform.localScale.y   1, transform.localScale.z  1);
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I change the scale of the "player" on `Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)` And back again to the original scale size when released.

I would love a helping hand with this problem.

Thanks alot for your time.

**Update:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RobotController : MonoBehaviour {
//This will be our maximum speed as we will always be multiplying by 1
public float maxSpeed = 2f;
public GameObject player;
public GameObject sprite;
//a boolean value to represent whether we are facing left or not
bool facingLeft = true;
//a value to represent our Animator
Animator anim;
//to check ground and to have a jumpforce we can change in the editor
bool grounded = true;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundRadius = 1f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public float jumpForce = 300f;
private bool isOnGround = false;
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        isOnGround = true;  
    }

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    anim.SetFloat ("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    isOnGround = false;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    //set anim to our animator
    anim = GetComponent <Animator>();
}


void FixedUpdate () {
    //set our vSpeed
    //set our grounded bool

    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
    //set ground in our Animator to match grounded
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");//Gives us of one if we are moving via the arrow keys
    //move our Players rigidbody
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);   
    //set our speed
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed",Mathf.Abs (move));
    //if we are moving left but not facing left flip, and vice versa
    if (move > 0 && !facingLeft) {

        Flip ();
    } else if (move < 0 && facingLeft) {
        Flip ();
    }

}

void Update(){
    if ((isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) || (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))) {
        anim.SetBool("Ground",false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
    }
    if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
    {

    }
}

//flip if needed
void Flip(){
    facingLeft = !facingLeft;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the gameobject l**ocal scale** on key **down** and **up**

```
void Update(){


    if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 

           gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);

     if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 

           gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


    }
```

Comment: player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); Returns an error

UnassignedReferenceException: The variable player of RobotController has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the player variable of the RobotController script in the inspector.
RobotController.Update () (at Assets/Script/RobotController.cs:70)

Comment: is there anything assigned to player

Comment: so what did you assigned to player

Comment: if this script is attached to the gameobject you want to rescale you use gameObject instead of player in my code , i edited see again